# Why my normal distribution is cutted when overlap with histogram

Tags: r, histogram, normal-distribution

Im new in R. I ploted a histogram with its normal distribution, but the line of the normal distribution is cutted on top. How do I fix it?

The code is the next one:

```
> d=read.csv("d.csv")
> d=d$d
> hist(d, freq = F,
+      ylab = "Casualities",
+      xlab = "Meters", main = "")
> 
> curve(dnorm(x, mean(d), sd(d)),
+       col = "blue", lwd = 3, add = TRUE)
```

And the graph looks like this:

[image: graph]

I already tried the ylim=350000 inside the hist function like this:

```
hist(d, freq = F,
+      ylab = "Casualities",
+      xlab = "Meters", main = "", ylim=350000)
```

And the result is this:

[image: graph]

Comment: Use the `ylim =` option inside the hist function.

Comment: It didn´t worked, do you have another tip?

Comment: You need `ylim = c(0,350000)`

Comment: you could also plot the curve first

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 but then the lines of the hist would cover the curve an look a bit ugly I think